# Elif statement syntax error: invalid syntax?

Tags: python

Here is my code as show below:

```
menu= "Welcome to the menu\n"                                     \
+     "Please select an option below:\n"                          \
+ (   "0 - Enter a number\n"   + "1 - Display current number\n" + \
"2 - Divisibility checking\n"  + "3 - Perfect checking\n"       + \
"4 - Triangular checking\n"    + "5 - Quit\n" )
x == ("")
while option!=5:                                                  # <<< Q2
    print(menu) 
    option= int(input("Enter option: "))
    if option==0:
        x= int(input("What is your number?: "))
        while x <=0:
             x= int(input("Must be positive, please! What is your number?: ")
    elif option==1:                                               # <<< Q1
        print("The current number is", x)
        elif (x == ""):
            print("No number yet - Please input a number and try again.")
            x= int(input("What is your number?: "))
```

**Q1:**
I was wondering why I kept getting an error message for `line 14` of my code, for the second `elif` statement.

**Q2:**
I was also wondering how, for my first `while` statement, I might define "`option`" for `option!=5` and then `print` the menu if I had not prompted the user to enter an option yet.

Any help on these two cases would really be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you read the code? Do you know what the `elif` belongs to?

Comment: you cannot nest an elif statement like you have in `elif (x == "")` also `x == ("")` before your while loop is doing nothing.

Comment: You have forgotten to close the `int()` parentheses on the preceding line.

Answer (score 0):

concerning your second elif-statement, I think you got the nesting wrong.

You have one outer decision tree, where you go through the available option, the tree is:

```
if option == 0 --> do a
elif option == 1 --> do b
elif option == 2 --> do c and so on
```

You don't need in inner elif, because it is NOT an else statement to the chosen option. You are just starting a new decision tree (You try to find if x is already assigned and if not ask for a number, otherwise show the number). Therefore the correct code should be:

```
elif option == 1:
    if x == "":
        print("No number yet - Please input a number and try again.")
        x= int(input("What is your number?: "))
    else: 
        print("The current number is", x)
elif option == 2 
    --> Handling of option 2
```

This should work. I took the freedom to put the if-statement first, otherwise you would get the output

```
"The current number is  "
"No number yet - Please input a number and try again."...
```

I think this is pretty much what Ignacio meant, when he asked, if you knew what the elif belongs to.

Comment: I think you missed the most important problem, which is that there is a missing `)`.

Comment: This is truly a problem and was correctly pointed out by Martijn, but as she mentioned a problem at the second elif-statement (so the edit is wrong, Q1 should be marked two lines further down in the code), I still think that the wrongly indented elif is her problem.